# Why does my font-size display differently on firefox vs. chrome mobile browsers?

Tags: cross-browser, font-size

I've been trying to find an answer to this, but no luck so far. Below is a screenshot, side by side (left is firefox, right is chrome). Same html, same css, totally different display of font-size and line-height.

Any help would be hugely appreciated. The left (firefox's display) is the result I want on chrome also.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every browsers have different default values, even though most of them are same.

Designers usually tackle this problem by normalizing/reseting the default browser values using a [Normalize Script](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/).

You can read about this more in this [article.](https://css-tricks.com/reboot-resets-reasoning/)

Comment: This doesn't work. I'm using this css file and font sizes are still different in Chrome and Firefox. And it's the same for any page on the web that I can see. For instance, look at https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-size.asp in both browsers.